# youtube url in video tag HTML

Tags: html, jsp, url, youtube

I have to incorporate a YouTube video in a HTML page using a jsp.. i already tried with iframe but i don't visualize the video on chrome and on firefox i had the error "i don't found any format or MIME type supported".. any idea?? i post the part of my code

```html
<video>
     <source src="<cms:contentshow element="UrlVideo"/>" >
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

A YouTube URL is going to point to an HTML document, not a video file. YouTube do not allow direct access to their video files. If you want to embed a video from YouTube, use the embedding code they provide when you click on "Share" in their UI.